# Is it possible to eager load a tree with Entity Framework levelwise?

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-6, eager-loading

I'm using Entity Framework 6 to load a tree structure. Due to the number of levels in the tree, I don't want to use a lot of includes, as the cross-product would be too big. I'm using a smaller example here for explanation.

```
public class Hospital 
{ 
    public virtual List<Station> Stations {get;set;}
    public virtual Contact Contact {get;set;}
    public virtual string Uid {get;set;}
}

public class Station
{ 
    public virtual List<Patient> Patients {get;set;}
    public virtual Contact Contact {get;set;}
}

public class Patient
{ 
    public virtual List<Medication> Medications{get;set;}
    public virtual string Name {get;set;}
}
```

I tried to do something like this:

```
var hospital = context.Hospitals
                      .Include(h => h.Contact)
                      .Where(h => h.Uid == myUid);
var stations = hospital.SelectMany(h => h.Stations).Include(s => s.Contact);
var patients = stations.SelectMany(s => s.Patients);
var medications = patients.SelectMany(p => p.Medications);

var myHospital = hospital.Single();
stations.ToList();
patients.ToList();
medications.ToList();
```

In my understanding this should issue 4 queries, and entity framework should fix up the associations in memory. Although the 4 queries are issued, I noticed that Entity Framework is still lazy loading, when I tried to navigate through the tree in memory. this does not seem to apply for the List of stations, but for the leaf levels (e.g.patient, medications,..)

Also I noticed, that if I disable lazy loading, I can easily navigate through the tree already, so the data should be loaded already. However I would prefer not to disable lazy loading.

Can someone explain to me why EF lazy loads already loaded properties?

Comment: Relationship fixup doesn't mark collections as loaded. You should either disable lazy loading, or load the tree while temporarily disabling proxy creation.

Comment: thanks, that sounds a bit strange to me, but is good to know.

Comment: Not strange at all. Relationship fixup never guarantees a collection to have been populated completely.

Comment: ok, that makes sense - is there any way to mark the collection as loaded manually?

Comment: No, there isn't.